# GORM foreign key doesn't seem to add proper fields

Tags: postgresql, go, foreign-keys, go-gorm

I have the following model:

```
type Drink struct {
    gorm.Model           // Adds some metadata fields to the table
    ID         uuid.UUID `gorm:"type:uuid;primary key"`
    Name       string    `gorm:"index;not null;"`
    Volume     float64   `gorm:"not null;type:decimal(10,2)"`
    ABV        float64   `gorm:"not null;type:decimal(10,2);"`
    Price      float64   `gorm:"not null;type:decimal(10,2);"`
    Location   Location  `gorm:"ForeignKey:DrinkID;"`
}

type Location struct {
    gorm.Model           // Adds some metadata fields to the table
    ID         uuid.UUID `gorm:"primary key;type:uuid"`
    DrinkID    uuid.UUID
    Name       string `gorm:"not null;"`
    Address    string `gorm:"not null;type:decimal(10,2)"`
    Phone      int    `gorm:"not null;type:decimal(10,0);"`
}
```

however, when I run the program, it adds both tables, however there is no location field in the Drink table.
My database looks like this after the migrations, regardless of whether I drop the tables previously:
[image: database after migration]

I have a sneaking feeling it might be because I am not using the gorm default ID, but if that's the case can anyone point me to how to override the default ID with a UUID instead of a uint the proper way? or if that's not even the issue, please, I've been working on this for a few days now and I really don't want to take the "easy" road of just using the defaults gorm provides, I actually want to understand what is going on here and how to properly do what I am trying to do. I am getting no errors when running the API, and the migration appears to run as well, it's just the fields I have defined are not actually showing up in the database, which means that the frontend won't be able to add data properly.

What I WANT to happen here is that a list of stores will be available in the front-end, and when a user adds a drink, they will have to select from that list of stores. Each drink added should only have 1 store, as the drinks prices at different stores would be different. So technically there would be many "repeated" drinks in the drink table, but connected to different Locations.

Comment: What is the relation between drink and location? You use fields like `DrinkId` to establish relations. When foreign key relations are specified, gorm allows you to `preload` references to other models.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- First point is as you are using custom primary key, you should not use `gorm.Model` as it contains `ID` field in it. [Reference](https://gorm.io/docs/models.html#gorm-Model)
- Second point is according to your description, `store` (location) has one to
  many relationship with `drink`. That means a store can have multiple
  drinks but a drink should belong to only one store. In `one-to-many`
  relationship there should be a reference or relation id in the `many`
  side. That means in your case in `drink` table. Then your struct
  should look like this:

#### MyModel Struct

```
type MyModel struct {
  CreatedAt time.Time
  UpdatedAt time.Time
  DeletedAt gorm.DeletedAt `gorm:"index"`
}
```

#### Location Struct (Store)

```
type Location struct {
    MyModel
    ID         uuid.UUID `gorm:"primary key;type:uuid"`
    // other columns...
    Drinks     []Drink 
}
```

#### Drink Struct

```
type Drink struct {
    MyModel
    ID         uuid.UUID `gorm:"type:uuid;primary key"`
    //other columns...
    LocationID   uuid.UUID// This is important
}
```

Then [gorm](https://gorm.io/docs/has_many.html#Has-Many) will automatically consider LocationID in `drink` table will be referring the ID field of Location Table. You can also explicitly instruct this to gorm using `gorm:"foreignKey:LocationID;references:ID"` in Location struct's Drinks array field.

[Reference](https://gorm.io/docs/has_many.html#Has-Many)

Comment: I am going to try this in my code but I think the issue is exactly what you've stated, the drinkID isn't referenced properly due to the gorm.model, and then now that I think about it, the store will need to store many drinks so I need the []Drinks slice for a one -> many.
I'll accept this as the answer as soon as I verify it works, but thank you so much for the advice!

Comment: Looks like that was the exact issue, I didn't properly understand how the gorm.Model was working, once I redefined that it seems to be working now. 

Using a one-to-many relationship was also helpful, I hadn't run into that issue yet but I certainly would have in short order, so you probably saved me a few hours at minimum on that as well.

Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks @jhax. It's my first accepted answer in Stack Overflow.