# Not able to create HasMany relationship between structs in a go app

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

I'm trying to create association between two go structs with Gorm for a db creation.
This is the only thing I have come up, but's not a real relationship, and code becomes complicated.
I would love to be able to have proper relationship between those two structs as the norm guide suggests.

The json to my endpoint looks like this

```
{
    "name": "VAL-1",
    "measurements": [
        {"width": 7677, "quantity": 7},
        {"width": 7777, "quantity": 3},
        {"width": 5677, "quantity": 2}
    ]
}
```

```
type Measurement struct {
    ID       uint `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    Width    int  `json:"width" gorm:"not null"`
    Height   int
    Thicknes int
    Quantity int
    Type     string
}
```

```
type BluePrint struct {
    Name                string
    BluePrintDefinition BluePrintDefinition `gorm:"foreignKey:Name"`
    MeasurementID       uint
    Measurements        []Measurement `gorm:"-"`
}
```

And the code that take cares of create is following

```
// TODO: encapsulate in transaction
func (bluePrint *BluePrint) CreateBluePrint(db *gorm.DB) *apiError.ErrorResp {
    dump.P(bluePrint)

    // first create BluePrint definition record
    if result := db.Create(&BluePrintDefinition{Name: bluePrint.Name, InventoryID: 2}); result.Error != nil {
        return apiError.New(apiError.WithDetails(result.Error))
    }

    // bulk create measurements records
    if err := db.Create(&bluePrint.Measurements).Error; err != nil {
        return apiError.New(apiError.WithDetails(err))
    }

    // create slice of bluePrint objects for each individual measurement record.
    bluePrints := []BluePrint{}
    for _, measurement := range bluePrint.Measurements {
        bluePrints = append(bluePrints, BluePrint{
            Name:          bluePrint.Name,
            MeasurementID: measurement.ID,
        })
    }

    // bulk create record in BluePrints for each individual measurement record.
    if err := db.Create(&bluePrints).Error; err != nil {
        return apiError.New(apiError.WithDetails(err))
    }

    return nil
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GORM foreign key doesn't seem to add proper fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73955463/gorm-foreign-key-doesnt-seem-to-add-proper-fields)